# Volume change has no effect on SDK7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wrote a custom Music player using the interface MediaPlayer and SongLibrary. However, when I try to change the volume of the music played, I cant hear the change in volume. I have used a slider as a volume control and wrote the following code to change the media volume:

The slider values are initialized as follows:

```
slider1.Minimum = 0; //maps to wp7 volume 0.0
slider1.Maximum = 10; //maps to  wp7 colume 1.0
slider1.Value = 8; //maps to wp7 default volume 0.85
```

The volume change code is as follows:

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
  MediaPlayer.Volume = (float)((slider1.Value)/10.0);
}
```

Even if I hardcode the volume to 0, I can hear the music.

This is tested on WP7 SDKv7.1

Is this a bug in the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that this is a hardware bug with HTC WP7 devices. Volume will work correctly in the emulator as well as non-HTC phones.

Answer (score 0):

There's three things to keep in mind when trying using the `MediaPlayer.Volume` property:

- It doesn't work if you play a song from zune (stored in the Musique & Videos hub of the phone). Only for your app's custom musics.
- You have to set the Volume property after starting the music. It will be ignored if you do it before
- There's a few known bugs on the emulator. When it doesn't work, always try once on the device to make sure

Comment: There is a problem with `SoundInstance` `Volume` on HTC devices. With `MediaPlayer` maybe too. http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65291/567325.aspx